# How to restore a database without being granted sysadmin

Tags: sql-server

I have a backup of a DB. In that DB's original state I was not a `sysadmin`.

When restore it I am granted the `sysadmin` role.

Is there a way that I can restore the database without being granted `sysadmin`?

I want to do this as I am testing an application which behaves differently if the logged-on user has the `sysadmin` role.

Thanks

Comment: Try DBCREATOR role with db_backupoperator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sysadmin is a server-level role. Restoring a database on a server shouldn't affect whether you are a member of that, or any other server-level role.